# How to do server side scripting

Tags: android

i have to make a script file in server-side that can accept my username and password and authenticate if authentication is success then i can response positive else response negative.
**but how to do server-side scripting???**please reply

Answer (score 1):

That depends very much on your script. For example if you have a PHP script you'll need a server with a PHP interpreter installed and  configured, then you just access the script's URL like any regular webpage.

You might want to look into simply tutorials about deploying php scripts and webpages(even if your script isn't PHP, it should be very similar)

Answer (score 0):

How you do it depends on what you are running on the server. There are heaps of tutorials online for this sort of thing - for example [this php tutorial](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Writing-a-Basic-Authentication-System-in-PHP/).